# Will samsung gear S2 be compatible with red mi note 3?

Tags: android-wear, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I am thinking of buying [Samsung Gear S2](http://www.androidcentral.com/here-are-phones-compatible-samsung-gear-s2)

It says that it will be compatible with any android phones with higher than 1.5 GB ram.

I have Xiaomi Red mi note 3. Not a pro one. However, the only difference that I know is that red mi note 3 doesn't have extra space for sd card

Answer (score 0):

As per [compliance list released by Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/gear-s2/device-compatibility/) mi 3 is compatible

[image]